# How to store data value in protobuf?

Tags: json, xml, serialization, protocol-buffers, encode

In JSON we can do:

```
{"age": 30}
```

The key is `age`, and its value is `30`. Both are there, ready to be used.

But, how can one do that in protobuf? In protobuf, you can only do:

```
message MyMessage {    
   int age = 1;
}
```

How to incorporate the value `30`? How can I use it if it is not even there.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```proto
message MyMessage {    
   int age = 1;
}
```

is declaring the *schema* of the data - not any particular instance / values; this would be comparable to a type definition in most languages.

How you *instantiate* that and assign per-instance contents depends on the specific language and runtime that you're using. For example, with the C# implementation, this message could be used something like:

```
var obj = new MyMessage { age = 30 };
// now serialize obj to somewhere
```

Comment: So does that mean, protobuf ís for "type definition" only? And one have to instantiate/assign values elsewhere.

Comment: @ledang the .proto schema syntax is for type definitions only, not data; the *data* comes at runtime; it goes without saying that protobuf supports both - a serializer that allowed you to define types but not deal with instance data would be useless. However, the idea is that you use the .proto schema syntax to generate code *for your chosen platform/language*, and then the per-instance data related stuff happens *there*. For example, you might be working in Java, or C++, or C#, etc; the .proto that describes the schema is the same; the code to create/assign per-instance data is per-language.